# Angular new router - Nested components and routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-new-router

I'm playing around with the new angular router and wanted to try out a use case where I have a component and a *nested component*.

Below there's the JavaScript code I wrote to define the two components and the routes:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngNewRouter'])
  .controller('AppController', function ($router) {

  $router.config([
    {
      path: '/parent',
      component: 'parent'
    }
  ]);

})
.controller('ParentController', function ($router) {

  this.name = 'Parent component';
  $router.config([
    {
      path: '/child',
      component: 'child'
    }
  ]);

})
.controller('ChildController', function () {

  this.name = 'Child component';

})
.config(function ($componentLoaderProvider) {

  $componentLoaderProvider.setTemplateMapping(function (compName) {
    return compName + '.html';
  });  

});
```

And the HTML part:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body ng-controller="AppController as app">
    <a ng-link="parent">Go to parent</a>
    <div ng-viewport></div>
</body>

<!-- parent.html -->
{{ parent.name }}<br/>
<a ng-link="child">Show child</a>
<div ng-viewport></div>

<!-- child.html -->
{{ child.name }}
```

Here's a Plunker containing the code above: http://plnkr.co/edit/yWCFgXQI491EYvIldjyR

Based on this code I have the following questions/issues:

1. If I go to the lowest level (#/parent/child) and then hit refresh, the parent and child components are not shown anymore. The route is not restored even though the URL still is the same. Do I need to *renavigate* or do something to restore the page's state? This is a very basic feature to be able to bookmark URLs.
2. If I go to the lowest level (#/parent/child) and then click on the *Go to parent* link, the URL is correctly set to *#/parent* but the child component is still visible.

Comment: this issue might be related: https://github.com/angular/router/issues/222

Comment: some more discussion is going on in https://github.com/angular/router/issues/117 as well

Comment: I also opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/router/issues/334

Comment: why aren't you using ui.router for multi states ?

Comment: I suggest you to use ui.router instead of this $router.
It has more documentation and not so raw code [ui.router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

Comment: Isn't this router deprecated? Can you add a link to the exact page you're basing your code on?

Comment: As others had said go with ui.router

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that strike me, is that you're not using any identifier that points to the parent and child that you want to display.

How/where do you get this information? Your url would look a lot nicer (and maybe even solve the issue if it were written as

```
/parent/:parentId/
```

or

```
/parent/:parentId/child/:childId
```

I've mostly used routeProvider and routeParameters myself, and they provide this functionality without any hassle but as this exercise seems to be purely academic, i'd try to read through what the module is actually doing as well as checking whether there is a related issue among the github issues.

Further, [this page from the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) seem to shed some light on the issue.

If this is not at all helping you, would you consider helping us out by giving us some more information?

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## This is Old Way #

```js
 var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "parent.htm"
    })
    .when("/other", {
        templateUrl : "Default.htm"
    });
});
```

Comment: **Using new way we can do perform routing this .**


(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', ['parent', 'home', 'ngNewRouter'])
    .controller('AppController', function ($router) {
      this.header = 'TITLE';
      $router.config([
        {
          path: '/', component: 'home'
        },
        {
          path: '/parent', component: 'parent'
        }
      ]);
    });
})();
**I hope this will work .**

Answer (score 1):

```js
**Using new way we can do perform routing this .**


(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', ['parent', 'home', 'ngNewRouter'])
    .controller('AppController', function ($router) {
      this.header = 'TITLE';
      $router.config([
        {
          path: '/', component: 'home'
        },
        {
          path: '/parent', component: 'parent'
        }
      ]);
    });
})();
**I hope this will work .**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using [UI Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/).

You can also have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) if you want to use nested routes.

Comment: Incomplete answer